# iOS Popover Does Not Go Away After Dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, popover, uipopovercontroller

We have a view controller presents a popover from a `UIBarButtonItem` when clicked. The popover shows up fine, but when we click the Cancel button inside the popover, which calls `dismiss(_:completion:)`, or when we tap outside the popover, the popover disappears. However, everything inside the view controller that presented the popover remains unclickable. When we inspected the view hierarchy, we can see the popover, along with its `UITrasitionView` is still on the window and is blocking the view controller behind it, even though in the simulator the popover is no longer visible. What could be the cause?

We have set the `buttonBarItem` of the popover controller correctly and it's showing up correctly. It's just when it's dismissed that the problem comes in.

The code looks just like this:

```
let controller = SettingsController() // the settings controller
controller.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender // the UIBarButtonItem
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Nothing changes EVEN IF we replace the `SettingsController` with a plain `UIViewController`.

P.S. This view controller that presents the view controller uses custom transition, but after inspecting the codes with breakpoints, we believe that this is not the cause for the custom transition delegate is not involved in the presenting/dismissing of the popover.

Comment: Can you include the code for dismiss ?

Comment: you have any ui task like `progress indicator` running behind?

Answer (score 1):

To Open a View

```
let vc = SettingsController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To close the view

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

is self ViewController embedded in the navigation controller ? If so, try
`self.navigationController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)`